# Как при выборе значения в ComboBox получить его текст?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как при выборе значения в ComboBox получить его текст? SelectedValue, Selecteditem не помогает. И как добавить несколько значений в ComboBox без добавления одинаковых?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    // *** Получение значения при выборе в ComboBox
    // Подключаем обработчик события - если значение нужно в момент выбора

    // Обработчик события при выборе значения из списка
    private void comboBoxInfo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Первый способ
        MessageBox.Show(comboBoxInfo.SelectedItem.ToString());
        // Второй способ
        MessageBox.Show(comboBoxInfo.Items[comboBoxInfo.SelectedIndex].ToString());
    }

       // *** Добавление группы значений без повторения

        // Массив новых значений
        string[] newValue = {
                                "Новое значение 1",
                                "Новое значение 2",
                                "Новое значение 3",
                                "Новое значение 4"
                            };

        // Перебираем массив в цикле
        foreach (string val in newValue)
        {
            // Проверяем наличие в списке и если нет - добавляем
            if (comboBoxInfo.FindString(val) == -1) comboBoxInfo.Items.Add(val);
        }
```

В WPF - почти также, только обработчик события будет называться чуть-чуть по другому и проверка наличия элемента в списке будет не FindString, а Items.IndexOf(val). Для WPF - это будет так:

```
    private void comboBoxInfo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Первый способ
        MessageBox.Show(comboBoxInfo.SelectedItem.ToString());
        // Второй способ
        MessageBox.Show(comboBoxInfo.Items[comboBoxInfo.SelectedIndex].ToString());

        // Массив новых значений
        string[] newValue = {
                            "Новое значение 1",
                            "Новое значение 2",
                            "Новое значение 3",
                            "Новое значение 4"
                        };

        // Перебираем массив в цикле
        foreach (string val in newValue)
        {
            // Проверяем наличие в списке и если нет - добавляем
            if (comboBoxInfo.Items.IndexOf(val) == -1) comboBoxInfo.Items.Add(val);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ComboBox1.SelectedItem.Content
```

Comment: В WPF нет такого свойства SelectedText

Comment: @Demon Ответ исправил

Answer (score 0):

можно использовать`comboBox4.DisplayMember.ToString()` тогда Вы сможете получить отображаемый в боксе элемент.